# Linking to an embedded file in word

Tags: html, hyperlink, ms-word

We have Word documents availible from an Intranet site. One of these documents has an embedded Excel Spreadsheet that I would like to link directly to but I can't find a solution anywere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question: you have word documents on some server, and the word documents have excel spreadsheets within them; and you want some URL that will link directly to the excel spreadsheets, bypassing the word documents?

To create hyperlinks within word:

- Right click where you want to insert the link within the Word
  document, click hyperlink. Fill out the box that comes up.
- If you want to link to a specific part of the document, you have to
  create a bookmark (Insert + Bookmark).

So in your case you may wish to do this on the excel sheet. **Note that there is no way to bypass opening the word document - the spreadsheet is embedded after all.**

But if you are going to treat this bookmark as an anchor tag for the purposes of linking directly to it (the browser focusing in on the speadsheet)...

I do not know if this applies to your version of word, but it has previously been the case that Word doesn't use the # syntax. Instead, it uses an \l switch (that's a lower
case L after the backslash) followed by the anchor name, as in

{HYPERLINK "http:// blah blah .com/archives/01.html" \l }

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to bypass opening the word doc if at all possible. The word doc belongs to a different department so I can't edit it unfortuntely, thanks for the info though.

Comment: @KieranQuinn any chance you could mark this as the accepted answer in that case? ;)